# Starting an activity from a random class

Tags: android

I've adapted the `GridInputProcessor` class of the 3D-Gallery (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/+/master/src/com/cooliris/media/GridInputProcessor.java
 ) so that it detects upward/downward swipes.

The detection of swipes works, but I now want to start another activity (or draw a bitmap on the currently displayed activity), but I seemingly can't use `startActivity(mContext, myIntent)`, because the class declaration is
`public final class GridInputProcessor implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {`
so it doesn't extend `Activity`...

Can I still start an Activity through this class, or how would I go about doing this? I have also tried sending a broadcast, but this is also not "implemented".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with re-using the context of an activity that I know is running at the time of the swipe (where the actual swipe occurs) via:

`theOtherActivitysContext.startActivity(...)`